# Android PHP query not working, works in client

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have an Android application, which communicates via php with mysql.

When I try to update database with Postman app it works correctly -updates database, but when I try to do the same thing using Android app, it does not work, no exception, everything works "correctly" but database is not updated. If I try to execute any other function in php from Android, it works.

PHP uses parameters first parameter is function to call, second is team id, third is current checkpoint and the last one is current checkpoint + 1 as following:

setCheckpointStatusResolved 4 0 1

PHP code:

```
if ($parameters[0]=="setCheckpointStatusResolved"){
$result = @mysqli_query($conn,"update `db`.checkpointstatus set   resolved=now(), checkpointstatus.checkpoint_id=".$parameters[3]." where checkpointstatus.team_id=".$parameters[1]." and checkpointstatus.checkpoint_id =".$parameters[2]."");

if (!$result){
print json_encode("Error!");

}else{
print json_encode("OK!");

}
}
```

Android code:

```
 public Checkpoint updateCurrentCheckpoint(int teamId, int currentCheckpointId) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(baseUrl.trim());
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        int next = currentCheckpointId + 1;
        wr.write("setCheckpointStatusResolved " + teamId + " " + currentCheckpointId + " " + next);
        wr.flush();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    Checkpoint checkpoint = getCurrentCheckpoint(LoginActivity.teamId);
    return checkpoint;
}
```

Any idea how to make it work in Android app?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing `@` operator obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your comments :) unfortunatelly I am not developing PHP side as I have almost no experience in that, so I have no right to edit that, but will let the responsible person know :)